# added form from ui_component not showing save button magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms, uicomponent

i am adding form through **ui_component** but not **save** and **back** button are not showing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form.sampleform_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form.sampleform_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Form</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="sampleform_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\SampleForm\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="sample_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
        <field name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sampleform</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <!-- This field has data type 'text' and standard 'input' form element and looks like input -->
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Some text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sampleform</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: add your edit.php block file code

Comment: there is no block code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding this in `data`

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form.sampleform_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form.sampleform_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Form</item>
    <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
    </item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\BackButton</item>
    <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\SaveButton</item>

    </item>
</argument>
```

**back button block**

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class BackButton
 */
class BackButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10,
            'on_click' =>''
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get URL for back (reset) button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/');
    }
}
```

**save button block**

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 * @package Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit
 */
class SaveButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save Block'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                'form-role' => 'save',
            ],
            'sort_order' => 90,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Qaisar, I'm following your post to create save button, but it is not working, on click it is redirecting on same page without updating data, also post  `GenericButton.php` code here, please reply?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari i updated the answer with complete code

Comment: Thanks for reply, but where are the `GenericButton.php` code and my save button showing `module/index/index` link instead `/module/folder/save`, while I have also added `submit_url`.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari   i don't have code right now but you can get idea from this file `vendor\magento\module_cms\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Edit\GenericButton.php`

Comment: I got the idea from your another post `https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139643/14039` but why save button not working?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari did you add `<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="test/test/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>` in **dataProvider**

Comment: Yes, I have added `submit_url` code in `dataSource`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have just added `'on_click' => '',` in `saveButton.php` and now save is working for me.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari welcome. glad you solved it :)