# adding save button with ui_component not working

Tags: magento2, forms, uicomponent

after adding the button in **ui_component**. i give  error  **500 Internal Server Error** not going to post values on **save controller**. It posting on current url. Example i am using for adding the button.

Question [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130732/added-form-from-ui-component-not-showing-save-button-magento-2)

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">categories_index_edit.category_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">categories_index_edit.category_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">News Category</item>
         <!-- <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">categories_index_edit</item>
        </item> -->
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\SaveButton</item>
           </item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>


    </argument>
```

error

> Notice: Undefined index: data in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/m2_module/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent
>   /ContentType/Json.php on line 71
>
> 0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/m2_module/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php
>
> (71): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined
>   index...', '/opt/lampp/htdo...', 71,  Array)
>
> 1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/m2_module/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(118): Magento
>   \Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form),
>   'templates /form/...')
>
> 2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/m2_module/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php(72):
>   Magento \Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()

Comment: Please post the 500 error in your question.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i think posting on same page will causing itbecause loading the same form again.

Comment: Well post the error from your server error log and we'll know. Assuming is never good in programming

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism it is about form element layout errors. add the error.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism the button is not redirect to save instead submit on current url via **ajax** any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searches i found that problem was with the magento version `ui_component form` is only working `magento 2.1`. After moving this code to `magento 2.1` solved the problem.

Comment: please edit the magento spellings in your post

Comment: You are welcome sir. you helped me many times.