# UI component save button controller magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, uicomponent, save

I have UI admin form xml file.

I've got **SaveButton.php** block file, but I need to save form in db. 
As far as I know I need controller.

How this controller would look like and in which directory it should be stored?

Comment: Are you created Admin Grid in Layout structure or ui component?

Comment: Please refer here for answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/346786/31436

Answer (score 2):

The location of the Save Controller class largely depends on UI Component configuration.

For example, the dataSource settings for the Customer UI form looks like this:

```
<dataSource name="...">
    <settings>
        ...
        <submitUrl path="customer/index/save"/>
    </settings>
```

This path leads us to a Controller file here:

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php
```

Following a similar pattern makes sense.

I suggest creating a data object from a data factory and then saving the object via it's repository.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-form.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html