# How to put a PHP function in a Button "on click" attribute?

Tags: magento2, php, uicomponent, forms, custom-button

Hi i'm new at magento2 and i want to put a PHP function in an "on click" attribute of a button on ui component form.

Specifically on this "Save Header" button.
[image: button]

So, actually i want to use this "Save Header" button to just save two fields of the form, the fields (Nome Header, Valor Header).

[image: form]

The "on click" attribute. In this "on click" i want to call a php function...

[image: on click]

routes.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="api" frontName="api">
        <module name="Hub_Api" />
    </route>
</router>
```

[image: directories]

------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------

So now my "SaveHeader" button is like that, but still don't working, maybe the url is passed wrong:
[image: new saveheader button]

SaveHeader.php (Controller):

```
namespace Hub\Api\Controller\Adminhtml\Data;
```

class SaveHeader extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $logger;

```
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * View  page action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    $txt = 'HUDSON SAVEHEADER : ';
    $this->logger->log('DEBUG', $txt);

}
```

}

Comment: you want to save button click and call the controller ???

Comment: Yes, actually i want to use this "Save Header" button to save just one field of the form. I will update the post with the entire form.

Comment: i am not sure but may be help you `Save Header` button controller path set this type https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/274310/85907

Comment: check other link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91071/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-admin-sales-order-view-in-magento2

Comment: Actually i created the button, but i want to put an php function on the "on click" attribute

Comment: a php function will not work as per your requirement, although you can use js for the same. on hitting the button the data can be saved through ajax and on ajax response you can populate your form

Comment: hey guys, now i got the problem that i don't know exactly how to call the controller url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    $message ='Are you sure you want to do this?';
    $url = $this->getUrl("api/data/deleteheader"); 
    return
        [
            'label' => __('Save Header'),
            'class' => 'myclass',
            'on_click' => 'confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$url}')',
            'sort_order' => 100
    ];
}
```

> You can write you php code into this controller action file.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Would be something like this? $url = 'Hub_Api/Controller/SaveHeader/id/' . $this->getDataId(); I don't know, i think i'm passing the url wrong.

Comment: give screenshot of your router.xml file for admin and controller action code syntax

Comment: hey, i put the code for routes.xml and the directories. The "SaveHeader" controller is in "Controller\Adminhtml\Data" directory

Comment: Please put like this  adminroutename/data/saveheader

Comment: please check my updated answer and update me

Comment: hey, i already tried this and still don't working... Could the error be on the Controller class?

Comment: So, i think the problem is on the "SaveHeader" button, because i can call the "SaveHeader" Controller using the construct of another controller.

Comment: I made it, but i used this : $url = $this->getUrl("api/data/deleteheader");

Answer (score 1):

This is my idea hope it help.
In `getButtonData()` function add `on_click` to javascript function something like 'saveHeader()'

add your template in layout call to UI form:
sample we have `MODULE-NAME_CONTROLLER-NAME-ACTION.xml` this content like

```
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
       <uiComponent name="your_ui_form"/>
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="XXX"  template="NAMESPACE_MODULENAME::html/js.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

In `js.phtml` file create new `saveHeader()` function call `ajax` to submit form element to your custom module controller (php).

This sample for js.phtml file content:

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function($){
            function saveHeader() {
                 $form = $('#formId');
                 $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'url',
                        data: {
                            xxx,
                            form_key: 'qiIiwjIPOdmrA0Uq',
                            return_session_messages_only: 1
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        showLoader: true,
                        context: $form
                    })
                    ...
           }
```

Good Luck!

Comment: For what i should replace the "xxx" ? and how i could call the controler by the button?

Comment: "xxx" are field you need send to save like `nome_api: $('input[name="nome_api"]').val()`
when you click button it will call javascript function is `saveHeader()` then it will submit data to `url`. Url is mean your php controller file in this file you can get data and save it.
All step above is mean get you "header" data and submit it to another php controller then save.

Comment: So i'm trying this but happens this exception: Invalid template file: 'Hub_Api::view/deleteheader.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'deleteheader'

Answer (score 1):

hello you can change your code with following code

```
$fieldset->addField('registered', 'button', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Send e-mail to all registered customers'),
            'value' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Button Caption'),
            'name'  => 'registered',
            'class' => 'form-button',
            'onclick' => "setLocation('your url')",
        ));
```

Comment: In 'your url' you mean the Controller url?

Comment: you can also write location.reload

Comment: So the url would be like $url = 'Hub_Api/Controller/SaveHeader/id/' . $this->getDataId(); ? i think i'm passing the url wrong.