# Save Button Redirecting to Same Admin Form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, php-7

I am working on a custom module in magneto 2. i am creating an admin form using UI Component, when i click on save button Page redirects to its self

> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\ProductSliders\Edit\SaveButton

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control

\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 * @package Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit
 */
class SaveButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                'form-role' => 'save',
            ],
            'sort_order' => 90,
        ];
    }
}
```

i have make buttons using Block here is my Edit.php Class

> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\ProductSliders\Edit

```
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    } 


    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'slider_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'FME_ProductSliders';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_productsliders';
        parent::_construct();

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('FME_ProductSliders::productsliders')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save'));
            $this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandcontinue',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => [
                            'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                -100
            );
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('save');
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('FME_ProductSliders::productsliders')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Delete'));
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('delete');
        }


    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text for header element depending on loaded page
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {

        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('fme_productsliders')->getId()) {
            return __(
                "Edit Sliders '%1'",
                $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('fme_productsliders')->getTitle())
            );
        } else {
            return __('New Sliders');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    /**
     * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
     * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
     *
     * @return string
     */


    public function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {

        return $this->getUrl(
            'fme_productsliders/*/save',
            ['_current' => true, 
            'back' => 'edit', 
            'active_tab' => '{{tab_id}}']
        );
    }


    /**
     * Prepare layout
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('overview') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'overview');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'overview');
                }
            };
        ";
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Here is my save.php controller

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Module;

```
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
            var $sliderFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \FME\ProductSliders\Model\ProductSlidersFactory $sliderFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->sliderFactory = $sliderFactory;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$data) {

            $this->_redirect('fme_productsliders/productsliders/edit');
            return;
        }
        try {
            $rowData = $this->sliderFactory->create();
            $rowData->setData($data);
            if (isset($data['slider_id'])) {
                $rowData->setEntityId($data['slider_id']);
            }
            $rowData->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        $this->_redirect('fme_productsliders/productsliders/index');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('FME_ProductSliders::save');
    }
}
```

i Need a Help if anyone can??

Comment: Please refer here for answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/346786/31436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help but i solved problem by adding

```
<item name="save" xsi:type="array"> 
<item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item> 
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">save</item> 
<item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item> </item>
```

i got help from [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139639/uicomponent-form-save-button-not-working])

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set current to `false`

```
public function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {

        return $this->getUrl(
            'fme_productsliders/*/save',
            ['_current' => false, 
            'back' => 'edit', 
            'active_tab' => '{{tab_id}}']
        );
    }
```

Update: Add a return in `execute` method

```
public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$data) {

            $this->_redirect('fme_productsliders/productsliders/edit');
            return;
        }
        try {
            $rowData = $this->sliderFactory->create();
            $rowData->setData($data);
            if (isset($data['slider_id'])) {
                $rowData->setEntityId($data['slider_id']);
            }
            $rowData->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        return $this->_redirect('fme_productsliders/productsliders/index');
    }
```

Comment: not working how can i check this method is called not not

Comment: @WaqarAli updated the answer please check

Comment: Thank you foyour help but i solved problem by adding  `<item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            </item>`

Comment: i got help from [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139639/uicomponent-form-save-button-not-working]